# MySQLi query in variable/function (that can be later used to echo content)

Tags: php, sql, string, mysqli, heredoc

So I'm stuck with a problem. I'm creating some kind of "templated" page (no, I can't use Twig or anything like that) in PHP, that will later be incremented with actual content.

My main problem here is to echo links in navbar. I'm using MaterializeCSS, so in order to make the navbar responsive is to write the links twice inside different ULs. I can easily echo it one time, like this:

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT id, pagename, filename FROM NavbarLinks";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    $navstructure =
         <<<HTML
         <header>
         <nav class="$primarycolor">
         <div class="container">
            <div class="nav-wrapper">
              <a href="#!" class="brand-logo">$sitename</a>
              <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">

HTML;
    echo $navstructure;
    //  output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo '<li><a href="' . $row['filename'] . '">' . $row['pagename'] . '</a></li>
        ' ;
    }

    }
    echo "
    </ul>
  </div>
  </div>
  </nav>
  </header>";

?>
```

This works with no errors. The problem is, I need that (according to MaterializeCSS specifications/documentation):

```
<nav>
<div class="nav-wrapper">
  <a href="#!" class="brand-logo">Logo</a>
  <a href="#" data-activates="mobile-demo" class="button-collapse"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
  <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
     // links
  </ul>
  <ul class="side-nav" id="mobile-demo">
    // links again
  </ul>
</div>
</nav>
```

So what I wanted to do was simple: Make a `navbar.php` and have the structure on a HEREDOC variable, and in the variable `$navbarlinks` I would print all the links I got from the first code I showed you. The problem for me is that putting the links in a variable instead of showing all the results will only print one, and I couldn't find a way to change this.

What should I do to have a `$navbarlinks` or `navbarlinks()` that prints all the mySQL results and work everywhere?

Comment: no longer practicing php but as far as i can remember html/css elements don't have to be pass to a variable.. you can just end php before the css elements and open php again from your loop

Comment: I can open PHP inside HTML that is inside PHP?

Comment: you can open html codes in php by escaping php see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to just put it in an array for later use. You should also try to separate your PHP from your HTML, this might be a good start but still needs things like [HTML escaping](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php). Note in particular the use of [alternative syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php) and [short echo tags](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php).

```
<?php
$links = [];
$sql = "SELECT id, pagename, filename FROM NavbarLinks";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $links[] = array_map('htmlspecialchars', $row);
    }
}
// PHP is finished now, here's the HTML
?>

<?php if (count($links)):?>

         <header>
         <nav class="<?=$primarycolor?>">
         <div class="container">
            <div class="nav-wrapper">
              <a href="#!" class="brand-logo"><?=$sitename?></a>
              <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
    <?php foreach ($links as $link):?>
                  <li><a href="<?=$link['filename']?>"><?=$link['pagename']?></a></li>
    <?php endforeach?>

              </ul>

              <ul class="side-nav" id="mobile-demo">
    <?php foreach ($links as $link):?>
                  <li><a href="<?=$link['filename']?>"><?=$link['pagename']?></a></li>
    <?php endforeach?>

            </ul>
            </div>
         </div>
         </nav>
         </header>
<?php endif?>
```

Comment: I'll try the code, but please keep in mind the navbar I need is acting like a reusable component, not a full page.

Comment: Sure, same philosophy applies though. Keep your logic separated from presentation as much as you can.

Comment: This is the solution. Thanks!

Comment: No problem. Do make sure to escape things like `$sitename` or `$primarycolor` with `htmlspecialchars()`.

Answer (score -1):

no longer practicing php but as far as i can remember html/css elements don't have to be pass to a variable.. you can just end php before the css elements and open php again from your loop

```
    <?php
    $sql = "SELECT id, pagename, filename FROM NavbarLinks";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        ?>

         <HTML
         <header>         
            <nav class="$primarycolor">
             <div class="container">
                <div class="nav-wrapper">
                  <a href="#!" class="brand-logo">  <?php=$sitename?> </a>
                  <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">


     <?php

        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo '<li><a href="' . $row['filename'] . '">' . $row['pagename'] . '</a></li>
            ' ;
        }

      ?>

        </ul>
      </div>
      </div>
      </nav>
      </header>";

<?php
  }
   ?>
<!-- end -->
```

Comment: No, my original code at least can use variables I defined, this one prints nothing and does not solve my problem.

Comment: firstly this code: if ($result->num_rows > 0) { -- don't know if this will give you something.

Comment: should be using mysqli_num_rows($result)